# Time reversal operator on conduction band edge function

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, time-reversal-symmetry

The bottom of the conduction band of Zinc Blende structure with grand representation $T_{d}$ symmetry group have a 2-dimensional representation at $k=0$ also known as the center of the Brillouin zone shown bellow:

$$\psi_{\Gamma_6} = \begin{pmatrix}\vert up \rangle \\ \vert down \rangle\end{pmatrix}$$

Which have a symmetry $\Gamma_{6}$ that can be expressed as the tensor product of a pure angular momentum state $\Gamma_{1}$  multiplied with a pure spinor representation $D_{1/2}$ given as follows:

$$\vert up \rangle = \vert iS \rangle \otimes \vert \frac{1}{2}  \ \ \frac{1}{2} \rangle =  \vert iS \uparrow \rangle   $$

$$\vert down \rangle = \vert iS \rangle \otimes \vert \frac{1}{2}  \ \ \frac{-1}{2} \rangle =  \vert iS \downarrow \rangle       $$

Where the $\vert S \rangle$ is taken as a real function representing states that transform as $\Gamma_{1}$ similar to an $s$ state with $\ell =0$, the anti-unitary time reversal operator is expressed as $T=K\sigma_{y}$, where $K$ is the complex conjugate operator while $\sigma_{y}$ is the y-component Pauli matrix. This operator can be used to alternate between the pair of states shown above in the doublet $\psi_{\Gamma_6}$ which are known as a Kramers pair. The action of this operator on a conduction band edge state is shown as follows:

$$T\vert up \rangle=i\vert down \rangle$$

$$T\vert down \rangle=-i\vert up \rangle$$

So according to my calculations which are obviously wrong, the time reversal operator is some kind of an involution, in mathematical words:

$$T^{2}\vert up \rangle=\vert up \rangle$$

which is clearly wrong in our case, since applying this anti-unitary operator two times must gives -1 when we are dealing with spinful states, which is not the case her unfortunately, so I really don't know where I went wrong, this behavior persist when dealing with valence band edge functions as well, keeping in mind that these states are successfully used to compute the dispersion relation $E(k)$ in the vicinity of $k=0$.